# Haskell equivalent of this Python code

Tags: python, haskell, code-translation

I'm learning Haskell after Python, and I thought that making a function that finds all the items in a sequence that aren't in another (where both sequences have elements that can be compared) would be an interesting exercise. I wrote some code for this in Python easily:

```
def inverse(seq, domain):
    ss = iter(seq)
    dd = iter(domain)
    while True:
        s = next(ss)
        while True:
            d = next(dd)
            if d != s:
                yield d
            if d >= s:
                break
```

(where both `seq` and `domain` are sorted)

However, I struggled to turn this code into Haskell. I presume I'd just use lists (that could be infinite) instead of `ss` and `dd`, and I guess I'd use `s = next(ss)` is the same as `s = head ss` and `ss = tail ss`, but I can't figure out how I'd translate that into Haskell. I also can't work out what I'd do with the two `while` loops. I presume I could use infinite recursion, but as there are two loops I don't know if that would need two functions or what.

Comment: `filter (not . (\`elem\` domain)) seq`. Or in plain english: `filter` out everything that is `not` `elem`ent of `domain`

Comment: I'm not so sure your python code does what you think it does.. It's not just the difference of two lists. Which by the way, you can calculate in Haskell with `Data.List.(\\)`

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.6/docs/src/Data-List-Ordered.html#minus

Comment: You can get coroutine-like behavior using `pipes`. You can get `iter` like behavior using `Foldable.toList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't quite get your code to work as advertised, but I think this snippet should work approximately the same way as yours, under two assumptions: X and Y are sorted, and all elements are unique.

We want to delete from `xx` all the elements from `yy`. At each step of the way, we just need to compare the first element of each of them (`x` and `y`, in the function definition). Three things can happen then:

- `x` is less than `y`, which means that `x` is not in `yy`, so we can accept `x`
- `x` equals `y`, we reject `x`
- `x` is greater than `y`, which means we need to move forward in `yy` before we can ascertain whether to reject or accept `x`

This is the function definition:

```
minus :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]  
minus xx@(x:xs) yy@(y:ys) = case (compare x y) of  
  LT -> x : minus xs yy  
  EQ ->     minus xs ys  
  GT ->     minus xx ys  
minus xs _  = xs
```

Comment: Generators in Python translate to "guarded" or "productive" recursion in Haskell. That's where we have something like `SomeConstructor foo bar (recursion goes here)`. If if that recursion loops forever, we can still pattern match on `SomeConstructor` so long as we don't force the evaluation of it's third field. In the example above, this is done with `x : ...`. If the theory behind this is interesting to you for whatever reason, coinduction, codata, and corecursion are the relevant concepts.

Comment: I think you mean `LT -> x : minus xs yy`.

Comment: The `GT` case looks strange: in the Python code when `d > s` we yield `d` and break, so we advance to both `xs` and `ys`, I think? Maybe `GT -> x : minus xs ys` performs the same?

Comment: @chi: I'd argue that's a bug in the python since it makes `inverse([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4])` yield 2, 3, 4

Comment: @rampion Ah, I see. I did not look at what the Python program was meant to do, only at what it did. :)